# Real Time Click/link counter

Tags: firebase

I've got this code...

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
    var x = 0;    
    function resetcounter() {
    x = 0;
    document.getElementById("counting").value = x;
    }

   function count() {
   if(x<50)
    {
      x += 1;
    }
    else
    {
        x=0;
    }
    document.getElementById("counting").value = x;
   }
   $('#btn').click(

         function() {
         count();
    });

    $('#reset').click(

    function() {
           resetcounter();
    });  
});
</script>
```

it works great. i need it however to update in real time. i would like to use firebase. 
How do i get the feed into firebase. basically i need this...everytime someone clicks a certain button on my site, there is counter keeping track how many times it has been clicked and it is shown to everyone on the page in real time.

Answer (score 2):

The general approach here is to move your 'x' variable out to Firebase and use that to back the state for the counter. Since we're doing a count across multiple potential clients, we wrap those updates with a transaction.

It would look something like this:

```
var x = new Firebase('https://countingex.firebaseio-demo.com/');

x.on('value', function f(s) {
    $('#counting').text(0 + s.val());
});

$('#btn').click(function() {
  x.transaction(function(current_value) {
    return current_value + 1;
  });
});

$('#reset').click(function() {
    x.set(0);
});
```

I've put a [working example up on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qgHPc/2/); take a look by opening it in multiple windows. I left out the conditional against the magic number 50 for the sake of simplicity.

To get started with other Firebase basics, I would recommend you take a look at our [interactive tutorial](https://www.firebase.com/tutorial/#gettingstarted).